# Unity - Animation Loops?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using an FBX 3D object file as a game object in my project which have further sub assemblies. Now i want to animate a part of the assembly. 
I followed this process:

1. Select the part which I want to animate.
2. In the animation panel create one animation.
3. Add property > transform > position
4. Using pivot, i move that part to the location where I want to animate.

**Challenges**

1. Animate in loop. Moreover if I Select animation file, it does not show Wrap mode 
   (   1. I don't want any loops in my animation, even after deselecting loop-time it does loop. - I dont know why?

   2. It is animating in reverse. suppose if the object needs to go from           position x:3 to position x:8 but it goes from position x:8 to position x:3
   3. the above point happens in loop. just like a ping pong)
2. Animates in reverse.
3. I take the whole animation as one loop i.e Part comes out of assembly and goes back and repeating for infinite time.

I want to stop the animation till the point it comes out.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The best way to animate mechanical game objects is from script. You can write several co-routines each will take care of one animation and of course multiple animations can happen at the same time. Inside the co-routine you can do what ever you want: loop, play reverse, play forward, ping-pong ... If you can use 3D softwares like `3Ds Max` or `blender` you can simplify it a bit by making some fixed animations  and then manipulate them from script.

Comment: Is there any other solution for the meantime because it will take a huge amount of time if i use 3ds or blender for animation as i do not hold much experience in these softwares

Comment: Then forget about animation clips and write scripts to manipulate them. For example, I had once written a script to control the aiming of a cannon. As u know, the cannon must rotate around y-axis to face the target and around x-axis coz it uses ballistic trajectory. I had also written a small physic simulation script to manipulate of the bullet fired from the cannon (it was a parabolic curve so you can consider it an animation too). As long as your animations do not involve bones you can do it in script without 3D softwares

Comment: @TaranpreetSingh I removed my answer since with the edit of your question, it does not answer anything related. And basically, I can't understand what you are trying to do.